# iOS - How does inheritance work?

Tags: ios, inheritance, setter, getter

I actually try to figure out how inheritance in Objective-C does work. My problem is, that my obj. allways returns "null".

Here is my Code:

Edit: Added rest of code.

```
//  ReportViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "IAPHelper.h"

@class Report, Category, GADBannerView;

@interface ReportViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate,     
NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {NSString* _werbung;}

@property (nonatomic, strong) GADBannerView *bannerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* werbung;

- (id)initWithReport:(Report *)report category:(Category *)category ;

@end


//  ReportViewController.m

#import "ReportViewController.h"
#import "IAPHelper.h"

@interface ReportViewController ()
- (void)loadReport;
- (void)setupFetchRequest;
- (void)resizeNavigationContentViewToHeight:(CGFloat)height;
- (NSString*) werbung;
- (void)setWerbung:(NSString *)newwerbung;
@end

@implementation ReportViewController
@synthesize werbung = _werbung;

-(NSString*) werbung {
return _werbung;
}

- (void)setWerbung:(NSString *)newwerbung {
_werbung= newwerbung;
}

//Werbung ausblenden
NSLog(@"Check for bought products");
if ([_werbung isEqual: @"gekauft"]) {
    self.bannerView.hidden = TRUE;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
{

         self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;


}

//ADMob

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
     if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
         _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20.0,850.0,728,90 )];}
 if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
     _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(-10,615.0,728,90 )];}
     if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
         _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(-10,615.0,728,90 )];}
     }
else
    _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,410,320,50 )];
//initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
//initwithframe:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320,50 )];

self.bannerView.adUnitID = @„xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx“;
self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
// Enable test ads on simulators.
[self.view addSubview:(_bannerView)];
request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, @„xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx“ ];
[self.bannerView loadRequest:request];

   //Werbung ausblenden
   NSLog(@"Check for bought products");
    if ([_werbung isEqual: @"gekauft"]) {
    self.bannerView.hidden = TRUE;
}

NSLog(@"%@",_werbung);
NSLog(@"%@",self.werbung);
}





//  IAPHelper.m
#import "IAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import "ReportViewController.h"

@interface IAPHelper () <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>

@end

@implementation IAPHelper

- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers
{
//self = [super init];
if ((self = [super init])) {

    // Store product identifiers
    _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;
    // Check for previously purchased products
    _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
        BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productIdentifier];
        if (productPurchased) {
            [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
            NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);

            if ([productIdentifier isEqual:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"]) {

              ReportViewController *rvc = [[ReportViewController alloc] init];
              rvc.werbung  = @"gekauft";


                NSLog(@"werbung gekauft!");
                NSLog(@"%@", rvc.werbung);     <- log's @"gekauft";
                } else {
            NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
        }
        }
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    }}
    return self;
 }
```

My question is: What I did wrong? Maybe you got a good tutorial for me too?

EDIT: You were right, it was not about inheritance. My solution is working with UserDefaults.

Comment: Can you tell, which objects goes `null` ?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",_werbung);           <- this is "null"
NSLog(@"%@",self.werbung);       <- this is also "null"

// was also marked in code btw :)

Comment: So where is the line of code where you set _werbung to something that isn't nil?

Comment: You mean that line:   rvc.werbung  = @"gekauft";   ?

Comment: The two lines that log null don't seem to be within any function context.

Comment: As @Paulw11 has pointed out, this can't be your actual code because it wouldn't compile -- the two NSLog lines (plus the chunk of code above it) are outside of any method context. Have you made a copy-paste error?

Comment: no, i just copied the "interesting" part out of it, but i can add the rest of this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a question of inheritance — inheritance governs what behaviour a subclass will acquire from its parent. The issue seems to be one of instances.

`ReportViewController` is a class. So it's not an actual actor. It's just the description of how any `ReportViewController`s that are created will act. Like a constitution.

When you call `alloc] init]` you create one new instance of the view controller. You then set the advertisement as bought on that instance. You don't put the instance anywhere or otherwise keep hold of it. That instance therefore ceases to exist.

Elsewhere, in a completely different instance, you check the advertisement value. Nobody has told that instance anything. So you see the `nil` values.

Think of it exactly the same as `NSString`. In the code below, should `stringB` change value?

```
NSMutableString *stringA = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableString *stringB = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[stringA appendString:@"Mo' string for ya'"];
```

Comment: Either that or wrong assumptions on when the [viewDidLoad](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) is called.

Comment: @A-Live I've lost count of the number of UIViewController subclasses I've seen that attempt to feed set properties to views, implicitly assuming that no properties will be set until after the view has been loaded. Though at least under iOS 6+ if time is tight you can just add a comment to the effect that what you're about to do is highly inefficient and add a forced view load in the setter...

Answer (score 1):

The `ReportViewController` that you're using to set the `werbung` value is not the same controller where you're checking the value. The one where you're doing the assignment is local to the method where it's being allocated.